# Basic Illustrator Help, Design not transparent, trapped in white box, how do i fix this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFByJ.jpg[image]

Got the world clipart thingy from the online and vector traced it ( maybe not completely, not sure ) and was trying to put it next to some text for a design. Problem is it's not transparent and is in this white box, so when i try to place it next to the text the white overlaps and doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options...

Option1: When using Image trace and configuring it to trace something, expand the **Advanced** area on the Image Trace Panel (Window > Image Trace) and then tick the **ignore white** option:

[image]

Option B: *After* you've traced. Click the **Expand** button on the control bar across the top of the screen. Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click and delete white-filled objects.